# Overriding method return type with incomplete derived class in C++

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I am writing a "filesystem" abstraction in C++, with the following inheritance hierarchy:

```
 [Node]
   ^
   |
   +----[Dir]
   |
   +----[File]
```

Where `Node` defines all the behavior identical to both (Name, time last modified, etc.) however, I have a `Node` method called `getParent()` that returns a type `Dir *`.  This works fine, because although `Dir.h` obviously needs to know the implementation specification in `Node.h`, `Node.h` doesn't need to know about what's in `Dir.h` so I can use a forward declaration.  Great.

However, I recently decided to add in multiple inheritance so I can support "snapshots" of the filesystem at a certain time.  These are read-only versions of the "live" `Node` `File` and `Dir` classes, and since the live versions can be read from as well as written to, I have each live version inherit from its snapshot dual:

```
[NodeSnapshot] <------ [Node]
    ^                    ^
    |                    |
    +---[DirSnapshot]<---+---[Dir]
    |                    |
    +---[FileSnapshot]<--+---[File]
```

Therefore, `Dir` inherits from both `Node` and `DirSnapshot`, and `File` inherits from both `FileSnapshot` and `Node`.  Everything looks good to be so far, until we get to the declaration of `getParent()`.  In `NodeSnapshot`, I return a `DirSnapshot *`.  No problem, I can use a forward declaration again.  However, in `Node`, I want to return `Dir *`.  I, as a programmer, know that `Dir` is a subtype of `DirSnapshot`, however the compiler has no way of knowing this because a forward declaration doesn't have any of this useful information embedded in it.

Is it possible to inform the compiler that this forward declaration is a subclass and therefore it shouldn't tell me that the return type of `Dir::getParent()` does not covary with that of `DirSnapshot::getParent()`?

Comment: "since the live versions can be read from as well as written to, I have each live version inherit from its snapshot dual". I am not convinced you need to inherit here.

Comment: Great!  I would love to hear alternative solutions here, as I'm not convinced either, but I would really like to be able to write generic code that can process either a `Node` or a `NodeSnapshot`, and inheritance is the best way I can think of to do that

Comment: I am not sure I understand what is the difference between a `File` and a `FileSnapshot`. Is `FileSnapshot` an object with file contents loaded into memory or is it rather `const File`?

Comment: It sounds like you certainly don't want multiple inheritance, at least conceptually; if you must, you'll surely want at least virtual inheritance so you don't have several copies of Node in the object.

Comment: As a tangentially-related note, "parent" is not a good thing for a `File` to have. With many filesystems, a file may be in several directories at once, or in none at all. Same goes for the "filename" concept. Files don't necessarily have names. Rather, directories link filenames and files.

Comment: @AlexanderChertov: That's close.  A "Snapshot" is a read-only view of a file.  It could be the current state of a file, or a previous version, etc.  This filesystem tracks a certain amount of history, and my representation of that is a Snapshot where I have a snapshot of directories, which contain snapshots of their files, etc. And of course, the current state of the filesystem tree is also a snapshot, it's just the most recent one.

Comment: @NicholasWilson: Yes, I am aware of the difference between Virtual and Non-Virtual inheritance, and most certainly want virtual inheritance, thanks for pointing this out

Comment: @n.m.: I am not modeling other filesystems, but rather providing a filesystem-like abstraction.  Therefore I explicitly don't allow a file to be parent-less or exist without a name.  This filesystem won't support fancy things like pipes, block device nodes, etc.... It's just normal files, directories, metadata on those files, etc. I am even skipping over the idea of an inode, instead using the path name as the unique identifier for data.  This means I don't get to do things like hard links easily, but that's okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to implement/emulate return type covariance without any language support, though solutions tend to be verbose. On the other hand, mutually recursive definitions are no problem. One needs to use non-virtual public (inline) functions that call virtual private functions. It is a useful technique, some even argue that all interfaces should be implemented like this.

Here's an example:

```
// forward declare classes
class A;
class B;
class AA;
class BB;

// parents
class A
{
    virtual B* getB_impl();
public:
    B* getB() { return getB_impl(); }
};
class B
{
    virtual A* getA_impl();
public:
    A* getA() { return getA_impl(); }
};

// kids
class AA : public A
{
    virtual BB* getBB_impl();
    B* getB_impl();
public:
    BB* getB() { return getBB_impl(); }
};
class BB : public B
{
    virtual AA* getAA_impl();
    A* getA_impl();
public:
    AA* getA() { return getAA_impl(); }
};

// implement parents
B* A::getB_impl() { return new B; }
A* B::getA_impl() { return new A; }

// implement kids
B* AA::getB_impl() { return getBB_impl(); }
BB* AA::getBB_impl() { return new BB; }
A* BB::getA_impl() { return getAA_impl(); }
AA* BB::getAA_impl() { return new AA; }

// check
A a; B b;
A* pa; B* pb;
AA aa; BB bb;
AA* paa; BB* pbb;

pa = b.getA();
pb = a.getB();

pa = bb.getA();
pb = aa.getB();

paa = bb.getA();
pbb = aa.getB();
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks.  It turns out that what I _really_ needed was a reminder of when NOT to make a function virtual! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should exclude multiple inheritance from your project.
Snapshot is associated with current state of filesystem/dir/file, so it's data.
You need inheritance when you don't want to replicate functional and inherit file and dir from node is acceptable. However since snapshot is data it is likely you need to move node data to some struct, special file/dir data to other structs, all of them will be returned or saved/restored on some functions callings, that will be overloaded due inheritance.

```
   [Node]       [Node Data]
   ^
   |
   +----[Dir]   [Node Data][Dir Special Data]
   |
   +----[File]  [Node Data][File Special Data]

virtual void Node::Snapshot()
{
//some code operating with Node Data (saving on disk for ex)
}
virtual void Dir::Snapshot()
{
Node::Snapshot();
//some code operating with Special Dir Data (saving on disk for ex)
}
virtual void File::Snapshot()
{
Node::Snapshot();
//some code operating with Special File Data (saving on disk for ex)
}
```